# lastValueFrom does not work while toPromise works

Tags: typescript, rxjs, es6-promise

While migrating from toPromise() to firstValueFrom/lastValueFrom due to the deprecation, I've run into an issue. Neither firstValueFrom/lastValueFrom works while toPromise() works as expected. The example code below shows my usecase. Neither of the 3 promises resolves on next(), while firstValueFrom should. Only toPromise() resolves on complete, while all 3 should. In the end the firstValueFrom/lastValueFrom produces EmptyError.

```
const subject = new Subject<boolean>();

setTimeout(async () => {
  await subject.toPromise();
  console.log("subject toPromise finished");
});

setTimeout(async () => {
  await firstValueFrom(subject);
  console.log("subject firstValueFrom finished");
});

setTimeout(async () => {
  await lastValueFrom(subject);
  console.log("subject lastValueFrom finished");
});

subject.next(true);
subject.complete();
```

Comment: Oh, I think this usecase is flowed because we only subscribe after calling next(). I'll fix this and see if that helps

Comment: This is one of the top reasons that `toPromise` was deprecated. In my opinion, `toPromise` is/was a fairly poor interface interface between the two libraries. In general, since Observables are a superset of promises, you can't convert one to the other without some loss of information. With `toPromise` you couldn't even know if the Observable emitted nothing or whether it emitted `undefined`. When you consider that you're switching from a lazy to an eager execution model already, it's so easy for random undefined variables to slip in where you don't expect and without explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that the firstValueFrom method was called after the Observable was completed. This was not a problem for toPromise() because it won't generate any errors in this case. But firstValueFrom/lastValueFrom generates an error if the Observable is already completed at the time when these are called.

The solution for me was to change the Subject to ReplaySubject, so when firstValueFrom/lastValueFrom is called the next() and complete() calls will be replayed.

*Subjective opinion:* I think this behavior is confusing. Generating a Promise from a source that is already finished should result in the same behavior as Promise.resolve(). Also if firstValueFrom/lastValueFrom is called between next() and complete() the resulting behavior is not that telling. When using Promises we usually operate with a single value that's either there or not there. So the original behavior of toPromise() where we resolve with undefined is a more logical default behavior.

Comment: This is a great question & answer. The situation you describe here as, "`firstValueFrom` method was called **after the Observable was completed**" I had the opposite problem, I used `lastValueFrom`, and my Observable **had not completed**, so the Promise value of `lastValueFrom` never resolved (example of my [issue here](https://playcode.io/1748941)). My comment is for other people like me -- I fixed by using `firstValueFrom` instead of `lastValueFrom`... ( `firstValueFrom` gets the next value from Subject's `.next()` (not the **very first** in the subject).